# How to calculate Cumulative Total of measure in power pivot without Date filter?

Tags: excel, dax, powerpivot, cumulative-sum

I have a power pivot table made out of a data model. It is filtered by gender and product group. 'PLM Qty' and 'Percentage Qty' are calculated fields. I need to create a column (desired column) that showing the cumulative total of 'Percentage Qty' regardless of the 'Material Name'. **This column should be flexible when a value in column 'Material Name' is expanded or collapsed.**

With the ordinary running total in a pivot table, the cumulative total always starts over for each material name. That's why I try using a power pivot.

[image]

I have tried to create a new calculated field with DAX patterns formula like this:

```
=CALCULATE(
           SUM([Percentage Qty]) ,
           FILTER( ALL(PLM_Div_Data[Material Name]) , [PLM Qty] <= MAX([PLM Qty] )
          )
)
```

But it keeps showing an error:

> Calculation error in measure 'PLM_Div_Data'[Cumulative Total]: Column
>   'PLM Qty' cannot be found or may not be used in this expression.

[image]

Is there any way to calculate MAX() and SUM() of a calculated field in this case?

Thank you for your help in advance!

Comment: For a cumulative total, you need to define the order somehow. Are you wanting to use material and color for the ordering?

Comment: I want to order it descending by 'PLM Qty'.

Comment: OK. That won't give you the column you specified in your first image though.

Comment: What do you mean? Is it impossible to order by a calculated field?

Comment: In your image, you are accumulating top-to-bottom rather than by `PLM Qty`. DAX has no inherent concept of top-to-bottom. You'd have to define an order and then use that.

Comment: when you say "calculated field", what exactly do you mean? Is it a DAX measure, or is it really a calculated field of a pivot table? What is the formula for "PLM Qty"?